# PHP Retrieve File to Tablet Fails

Tags: php, streaming, tablet

Our system stores files a user uploads above the webroot, with the filename getting stored in the DB. When a user wants to download, they click the filename, and our downloader page gets the file using the following...

```
header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.sprintf('%d', $filesize));
header('Expires: 0');

// check for IE only headers
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false)) {
   header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
   header('Pragma: public');
} else {
   header('Pragma: no-cache');
}

$handle = fopen($filepath, 'rb');
fpassthru($handle);
fclose($handle);
```

It seems to work in all browsers now, but when we try from iOS or Android devices, nothing happens. Hoping someone will see something obvious I've missed. I'm new to developing for handheld/tablet devices.

Thanks

Comment: double check the browser in question offers download support for such HTTP responses.

Comment: It works on Safari on a Mac/PC but iPhones, iPads just stall (no error). Same with the Honeycomb based Android tablets we've tested... I guess that would be a variation of Chrome, which it's also working fine for on the PC/Mac side.

Comment: Check the browser documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could check

> header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

instead of providing mime type.

Comment: Sorry... that's what $mime is equal to currently. It's a variable in case we want to specify possible mime types in an array